# IIS Exceptions throw debugger prompt on console and hang all IIS web sites

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

We have a win2012 server that hosts several web sites.

One of them (don't know which!) seems to have an issue, and when I am logged in to the server via rdp, there is a prompt to start a debugger (which does not work... unfortunately).

When this prompt is up, all the web sites pause (disaster!)

The event logs show no errors related to iis.

How to chase this down?

Comment: Does it happen when you log, or at random ? If when you log, please validate with another newly created account, to be sure it's not a start menu / executable wanting to run that throw an exception that the debugger want to catch.

Comment: the exception is from iis

Comment: The iis log show anything usefull ? Can you match the debugger timestamp with a request in the log ?

Comment: @samsmith Can you trigger this failure?

Comment: Are the various sites all run in their own application pools? If not, create a new application pool for each site. The 'bad' site should then only crash one pool and the other sites should continue running.